# Removing Default Outlook account in Windows Mail

Tags: email, windows-8.1

I am configuring a Windows Mail Account. I set up my Microsoft 365 subscription, and my email has been set up, however now I have two emails at the bottom of the mail app.

[image]

How do I go about removing the `Outlook` mail? Will this effect my Microsoft 365 Subscription?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I realised that with Microsoft 365 comes the venerable `Outlook`, so I binned off `Mail` in favour of more promising software.